# How to create baked toon/cell shaded outlines WITHOUT grease pencil

Tags: texturing

I'm desperately trying to figure out how to make outlines similar to the image below, without using grease pencil. Essentially I want to make my own marks and lines as textures so they can be imported into a game engine.

I believe grease pencil while perfect to render inside blender, can't be exported/baked as textures (or its gets exported exists as complex splines).

Any help or advice would be wonderful, thanks!

[image: cell shaded outlined]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LO-ZFt-knj4

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use the Paint Curves.

Here is the short but SUPER informative video about curve painting. It's filmed with an old version of blender, though in the 4.0.2 all stuff works exactly similar: [=youtube link=](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRwToPPGaZU)

---

**Note *1:**

You can plan-out strokes with the Annotate tool and then draw curves above the annotations.

I've made a quick example for you. All here is painted by curves - except for the solid dots in the eye-centers, which I've made by the single brush taps.

All the strokes are directly painted on a texture (no grease pencil used) :

---

[image]

---

**Note *2**

My lines here have a quite even width. Though you can add some jittering in the 'Stroke' option (in the brush settings)

---